# Strip process pid to log_file_name (weird behaviour when running from cron)

Tags: bash, awk, cron, sh

I am curious if anyone have similar issue when running scripts from cron. This line of script should copy opentsdb_daemon.log file to `opentsdb_daemon_with_pid.log`. Currently openTSDB is running on only one PID.

```
!/bin/sh

cp -f /opt/opentsdb/opentsdb-2.2.0/var/log/opentsdb/opentsdb_daemon.log "/opt/opentsdb/opentsdb-2.2.0/var/log/opentsdb/opentsdb_daemon_pid_$(ps -ef | grep [o]pentsdb  | awk '{print $2}').log
```

It runs ok. File `opentsdb_daemon_pid_76079.log` is created but when running fron cron it's creating something like this: `opentsdb_daemon_pid_63453?63454?76079.log`

I have tried to run it from diffrent cron users - with same effect. I would be extremely grateful for any advice.

Comment: run this `ps -ef | grep [o]pentsdb | awk '{print $2}'` separately. It'll give you a hint. Or post the output here, I'll give you a hint

Comment: I'm assuming it's a copy/paste error, but it misses a double quote at the end of the command

Comment: Also, does the cron daemon logged an error, and if so, could you provide it?

Comment: No, cron daemon does not log an error, I have eaten double quote at the end - but it's in the script

Comment: I have ran ps -ef | grep [o]pentsdb | awk '{print $2} separately. It returns: 7607

Answer (score 0):

The command `ps -ef | grep [o]pentsdb | awk '{print $2}'` should return multiple PID at the time cron run it, what you get is all the PID separated by "?"

The "?" is because `\n` is not correctly diplayed in the filename

I assume that it is because when cron executes the command, the command appears in the process list, so :

`grep [o]pentsdb` is also grep by `grep [o]pentsdb` ;)

You can determine it by the two consecutive PID 63453 and 63454 which are the process lines "cron execute the command xxx" and the child of this process which is the "command xxx"

Maybe a solution could be to add something like :

`$(ps -ef | grep [o]pentsdb |grep -Ev "grep|cron" | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of those nasty pids leaving only right pid ?

Comment: @PrzemysławPuchajda I would try to add a `|grep -Ev "grep|cron"` following the first `grep` to try to eliminate these lines

Comment: unfortunetely, efect is the same at the output  opentsdb_daemon_pid_73844?73845?76079.log

Comment: @PrzemysławPuchajda Can you past us the result of the `ps -ef | grep [o]pentsdb` when executed by cron ?

Comment: Still only one pid is returned: mapr      76079      1  5 May18 ?        05:50:06 java -enableassertions -enablesystemassertions -Xmx6000m -classpath /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf::/opt/mapr/opentsdb/opentsdb-2.2.0/share/opentsdb/*.jar:/opt/mapr/opentsdb/opentsdb-2.2.0/share/opentsdb:/opt/mapr/opentsdb/opentsdb-2.2.0/share/opentsdb/bin:/opt/mapr/opentsdb/opentsdb-2.2.0/share/opentsdb/lib/async-
...

Comment: Do you have access to pgrep ? you could try : `pgrep "[o]pentsdb"`. You can also specified the `--uid` to filter on the user executing the process if needed